# ARIMA parameter estimation from scratch

Tags: maximum-likelihood, estimation, arima

I am implementing ARIMA from scratch, and I am trying to understand how to estimate the parameters by the MLE + innovations algorithm approach. The likelihood is given by (as in Shumway and Stoffer: Time Series Analysis and Its applications)

\begin{equation}
L(\beta, \sigma_w^2) = (2\pi\sigma_w^2)^{-n/2} (r_1(\beta) \cdots r_n(\beta))^{-1/2} \operatorname{exp}\left(\frac{-S(\beta)}{2\sigma_w^2}\right)
\end{equation}

with

\begin{equation}
S(\beta) =\sum_{t=1}^{n}\frac{(x_t-x_t^{t-1}(\beta))^2}{r_t(\beta)}
\end{equation}

and where $r_{t+1}=(1-\phi_{tt}^2)r_t$ with $r_1 =\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\Psi_j^2$.

I understand that I must approximate $\beta$ and $\sigma_w$ numerically, and that finding $r_i$ is done through the innovations algorithm, but how is the $r_1$ found? In the textbook they give examples of AR(1) processes where an expression for $r_1$ is easily established, but what of a general ARMA(p,q) process?

Answer (score 0):

I found it easier to express everything in matrix algebra terms. Lets adopt a convention where all temporal variables are encoded as vectors with earliest time at the lowest position, e.g. for $x_t$:

$$
x_t \to \mathbf{x}=\left(\begin{array}\\\vdots\\x_1\\x_2\\x_3\\\vdots\end{array}\right)
$$

We can also define a matrix lag operator:

$$
\mathbf{L}=\left(\begin{array}\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0  &\dots & 0 & 0 & 0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0  & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 0 & 0  & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0  & \dots & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\dots \\
\dots \\
\dots \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0  & \dots & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
\end{array}\right)
$$

Now lets imagine something like ARMA(2,2) governing equation:

$$
\begin{align}
&\dots\\
x_{t-1}+a\cdot x_{t-2} + b\cdot x_{t-3}&=\epsilon_{t-1}+c\cdot\epsilon_{t-2}+d\cdot\epsilon_{t-3} \\
x_t+a\cdot x_{t-1} + b\cdot x_{t-2}&=\epsilon_t+c\cdot\epsilon_{t-1}+d\cdot\epsilon_{t-2}
\end{align}
$$

One can re-write this as:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}+a\mathbf{L}.\mathbf{x}+b\cdot\mathbf{L}^2.\mathbf{x}&=\boldsymbol{\epsilon}+c\mathbf{L}.\boldsymbol{\epsilon}+d\cdot\mathbf{L}^2.\boldsymbol{\epsilon} \\
\left(1-\alpha_1\mathbf{L}\right).\left(1-\alpha_2\mathbf{L}\right)\mathbf{x}&=\left(1-\beta_1\mathbf{L}\right).\left(1-\beta_2\mathbf{L}\right)\boldsymbol{\epsilon}
\end{align}
$$

Where $-\alpha_1-\alpha_2=a$ and  $\alpha_1\alpha_2=b$ etc. Note that irrespective of order such factorization is [always possible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_algebra), though $\alpha_{\dots}$ may need to be complex-valued. Next, note that, for every finite time-series (and, in practice it is always finite), since $\mathbf{L}$ is a nilpotent operator, one can write the inverse of the following bracket:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{M}_\alpha&=\left(1-\alpha\mathbf{L}\right)\\
\mathbf{M}_\alpha^{-1}&=1+\alpha\mathbf{L}+\alpha^2\mathbf{L}+\dots
\end{align}
$$

What is nice about finite [nilpotent matricies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nilpotent_matrix), the series above cannot be infinite, so it always converges in principle (numerical problems can arise for $|\alpha|>1$, but those are usually not considered for ARIMA anyway). Also note that $\det\left(\mathbf{M}_\alpha\right)=1$ and the same applies to its inverse.

We can now write:

$$
\begin{align}
\mathbf{x}&=\left(\mathbf{M}_{\alpha_1}^{-1}\dots\mathbf{M}_{\alpha_p}^{-1}\right).\left(\mathbf{M}_{\beta_1}\dots\mathbf{M}_{\beta_q}\right).\boldsymbol{\epsilon}
\end{align}
$$

For ARMA(p,q) and if $\epsilon_i\sim N\left(0,1\right)$ then $\mathbf{x}$ is a multivariate normally distributed variable with well known joint probability distribution and covariance matrix:

$$
\boldsymbol{\Sigma}=\left[\left(\mathbf{M}_{\alpha_1}^{-1}\dots\mathbf{M}_{\alpha_p}^{-1}\right).\left(\mathbf{M}_{\beta_1}\dots\mathbf{M}_{\beta_q}\right)\right]^T .\left[\left(\mathbf{M}_{\alpha_1}^{-1}\dots\mathbf{M}_{\alpha_p}^{-1}\right).\left(\mathbf{M}_{\beta_1}\dots\mathbf{M}_{\beta_q}\right)\right]
$$

You may need to do some extra work around the initial conditions, but mostly that is it. You can then optimize $\alpha_{\dots},\,\beta_{\dots}$ parameters with MLE, by feeding normal likelihood into the optimizer.

Comment: What do single dots means in your equations?

Comment: Nothing special, I mostly use them to delimit terms. So $\alpha\cdot x_t\equiv \alpha\,x_t$

Comment: I meant lower dots. What does $\mathbf{L}.\mathbf{x}$ mean? Does it differ from $\mathbf{L}\cdot \mathbf{x}$?

Comment: Quite often in literature middle dot between vectors means dot product, so I put lower dot between vectors to make it clear I don't mean it. All dots here are simply delimiters

Comment: Alright. I found the lower dots really confusing, as I had not seen them used like that before, especially together with central dots in the same equation. I think the notation could be improved, but that is just my opinion.